# How to rotate composable in glance

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, glance

I'm trying to create a custom analog clock widget using glance. In my case I need to apply some rotation on some composables. In composable function `Modifiers` have `rotate` extension function but this type of extension function is not available with `GlanceModifier`, so the question is how to apply rotation on some composables of Glance Widget?